# storing latitude and longitude for a route

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I want to store a bunch of routes which consists of a pair of latitude and longitude series in a database. I want to be able to get all the routes for a given key.

The way my table is set up now is the following:

RouteID Order Latitude Longitude

but a route can have many sets of latitude and longitude, so it becomes:

```
RouteID Order Latitude Longitude
1         0       X         Y
1         1       X         Y
1         2       X         Y
1         3       X         Y
1         4       X         Y
2         0       X         Y  
2         1       X         Y
```

I have another table called R, which has RouteID and it references to this Route table.
The question is:
1. Does this seems reasonable?

1. If not what is a better way of doing this

**UPDATE:**
So the other table is called TEMP and it has the following format

TempID RouteID UserID AttributeX AttributeY

when I do a SQL:

```
SELECT R.LATITUDE, R.LONGITUDE
FROM TEMP T, ROUTE R
WHERE T.UserID =1
ORDER BY R.ORDER ASC ;
```

And in my table currently UserID 1 has two routes, but it prints out each lattitude twice.
Is my SQL wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks OK to me.

But don't pollute the world with a table named `R`. Think about the guy coming after you, what does `R` mean?

The other table should probably be named `Routes` and this table should probably be named `RoutePoints` or just `Points` or something else informative.

And for the SQL, you have used a `CROSS JOIN` when you want to use a `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT R.LATITUDE, R.LONGITUDE
FROM TEMP T INNER JOIN ROUTE R ON T.ROUTEID = R.ROUTEID
WHERE T.UserID =1
ORDER BY R.ORDER ASC
```

That might work.

Comment: Yea.. I just put R as an example here.

Comment: Good to hear! You had me worried there. But the structure looks fine! If you need additional fields, such as a calculated distance between the points - add them later!

Comment: I updated my question... mind helping out? My SQL skill is rusty

Comment: If I also want to see username/userid then username/userid will be shown for every column?. So this table is not 3NF?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you want to use a space-filling-curve or a spatial index. I use it to store postcode and query them with just 1 operator indepedent of the zoom-level. You are welcome to download my class at phpclasses.org ( hilbert-curve ).

Answer (score 0):

A lot of it depends on what you want to do with this information after you have stored it.  If you just want to print out a map for a given route, your table setups could be ok.  If you wanted to know if two routes intersected or overlapped, you should probably learn more about Geogrpahic Information Systems (GIS).  [GIS Stackexchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com) is a good place to start asking questions.